# What is the name of an algebraic structure which is both a tensor space and a module.

Tags: abstract-algebra, terminology, manifolds

I am studying a set of high-dimensional arrays of complex numbers, which is both a tensor space (defined with the notion of addition and complex scalar product) and a module (defined with the same notion of addition and the notion of the product with a ring element). What is the formal name of this kind of structure?  Is there some literature that discusses this structure in more detail?

I think I can even embed a subset of this structure in it. The subset has a topology and is locally homeomorphic to a small open set of the unnamed structure, and has properties analogous to a canonical manifold. Since the unnamed structure is a module, can I call the constrained set a generalized manifold? Since the unnamed structure is also a vector space (i.e., a tensor space), the subset is also a canonical manifold.

What is the name of this topological subset?  The topological subset is established over a new commutative algebra called T-Algebra. The commutative t-algebra is both a finite-dimensional commutative ring and a vector space. I leave the URL of the t-algebra as follows if somebody wants to know more about the algebra.
https://github.com/liaoliang2020/talgebra

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119703/discussion-on-question-by-liang-liao-what-is-the-name-of-an-algebraic-structure).

Answer (score 1):

At this point, I'd just like to address the first question along with a comment you added later:

> What is the formal name of this kind of structure?

> The copy of $\mathbb{C} $ using the $C$'s action is the SAME to the $\mathbb{C}$ on $G$.

That being said, I do not see any reason to call this anything other than a $C$ module over the $\mathbb C$ algebra $C$.  Depending on how you use it, there may be justification for looking upon it as a $C, \mathbb C$ bimdoule, but I have not read your whole exposition.

---

I skimmed the linked arxiv papers briefly, and would offer the following feedback. I realize your articles aren't really directed at theoretical mathematicians, but passages like this are apt to cause reflexive eyerolls for algebraists:

> With appropriate operations,
> the t-scalars are trinitarian in the following sense. (1) T-scalars are generalized complex
> numbers. (2) T-scalars are elements of an algebraic ring. (3) T-scalars are elements of
> a linear space.

After parsing, an algebraist will simply see this:

> It's a $\mathbb C$ algebra.

Firstly, I'd recommend not using the phrase "algebraic ring" to mean "ring (in the sense of abstract algebra)" My impression is that the former is a hallmark of authors who are only tenuously familiar with rings.  There are, actually, [specialized uses](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1994039?seq=1) of the term.

Secondly, given your comments I've echoed at the top of this post, no algebraist would make such a big deal about the ring and linear space being separate. They'd just call it a module over a $\mathbb C$ algebra.

The first item on the list is also ostensibly subsumed under the observation you are working with a $\mathbb C$ algebra. And the whole `trinitarian` thing is a bit weird.

If this passage is any sign, there is a lot of reduction that could be made in order to eliminate unnecessarily fancy appellations in your work.  Simplifying terms will boost readability and transmissibility, and it will avert a lot of face-palming by some of your readers.

Perhaps even the word "t-scalar" or "t-algebra" should probably be replaced by something more informative.  While "t-scalar" might be original, it looks like "[T-algebra](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/homotopy+T-algebra)" is already something established.

"Inventing and naming a new algebra that has uses" is looked upon as a 19th century pursuit.  It seems like the venture is alive and well though. Nowadays the focus is on defining useful *classes* of algebras and what their properties are.  I'm not saying a paper on a particular algebra is automatically undesirable, but it will be important to know what *classes* of algebras are relevant to it so that you can leverage existing theory about those classes and focus on your applications.

---

I'd like to help with the second half of the post, but there are still some things to be clarified before that is possible.

Comment: There are subtle things between the "trinity" statement and just "$\mathbb{C}$-algebra". A complex algebra does not necessarily provide many properties that complex numbers have. The elements of complex algebra are defined with the notions of conjugates, rank, norm,  phrase angle, and non-trivial notions which are trivial to complex numbers.  If necessary to combine the "trinity" statement, it had better be  "It is a complex algebra which generalizes many notions of complex numbers"

Comment: You are right that the linked paper is not a full-sense math paper. It is not directed to theoretic algebraists. It is a passage directed to computer engineers, trying to connect them with a new algebra. Apparent things to algebraists might not be so to engineers and vice versa. The writing of the passage means to be not too terse for engineers to understand it. However, your advice on simplifying some writing is valued and accepted. And thanks for the clues on bimodule.